# Finding the weight of the final product in a reaction sequence

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

The question is:

> What is the molecular weight of the final product?
> $$\ce{Ph3C-Cl ->[NaCN] P1 ->[H3O+] P2 ->[Conc H2SO4][CH3OH]P3}$$

My products were:

$\mathrm P_1$ = $\ce{Ph3C-CN}$ (by S<sub>N</sub>); $\mathrm P_2$ = $\ce{Ph3C-COOH}$ (by hydrolysis); $\mathrm P_3$ = $\ce{Ph3C-COOCH3}$ (By esterification)

If this was correct, the answer should have been 302. But the correct answer is 274. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Your answer looks correct to me. The "official" answer looks to be in error

Comment: @Waylander, However, is the first step feasible? I was unable to find literature referencing the reaction between trityl chloride and sodium cyanide. Any preparation of triphenyl acetonitrile involved copper cyanide.

Comment: @SafdarFaisal  In the context of a question like this, I think the answer is yes. Like so many other questions, it has been set without reference to the literature by a teacher who thinks it should go like this. If it isn't this reaction, then what is P1? It becomes a much more difficult question.

Comment: @Waylander The answer might be incorrect but I doubt that is the case. It is supposed to be a ‘Spotlight’ question, which means it is tough and, by judging on previous spotlight questions given to us, unusual. All that I can think is there is something to do with Ph3C- group as it is not very commonly given in questions.

Comment: BTW I’ll get some hint (or solution) tomorrow. I’ll be sure to share it here.

Comment: @WhySee That will be interesting. I was playing around with the idea that P1 could be the isonitrile and P2 the N-formyl tritylamine, but I cannot make anything of MW284 from it by acid treatment - the iso-indolone is 285

Comment: Guys I’m extremely sorry. I just confirmed with my batch mates and the answer is 274 and not 284. I have corrected it in the question. I’m very very sorry for any trouble caused by the answer change.

Comment: 274 corresponds to 3 phenyls + C + 31. 31 = 16 (O) + 15 (CH3). So it looks like if CN goes on, it comes off because Ph3C+ is so stable, but in conc H2SO4 - probably adjusted carefully - OCH3 can go on, while the H2O produced reduces the acidity of the H2SO4 somewhat. But I just played with the numbers.

Comment: So are we proposing that P2 is triphenylacetic acid and it undeergoes an acid catalysed decarboxylation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in your first two steps. Cyanide adds to trityl chloride to give triphenylacetonitrile which is then hydrolysed in aqueous acid to triphenylacetic acid. In $\ce{H2SO4/MeOH}$ the acid is protonated and loses water to give the acylium cation ($\ce{Ph3C-CO+}$). This cation loses $\ce{CO}$ to give the very stable trityl cation ($\ce{Ph3C+}$) which is eventually captured by $\ce{MeOH}$ to give trityl methyl ether.

Comment: Wow. This is actually the correct explanation. I just confirmed today. Thanks.